# How can I create a static array in R

Tags: arrays, r, static

I need to create a static array for my data structure class and I chose to code in R instead of java.

How can I create a static array? I have tried

```
> array <- array(1:10, dim=c(1,10))
> array
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
```

but I can still add a 11th value to the array

```
> array[11] <- 11
> array
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: There's no such thing as fixed-size array or matrix in base R. If you only work with 2d arrays (matrices), check out `Matrix` package, which forbids explicit subscripting outside of defined size. Another option is to implement a formal S4 class, of course.

Answer (score 2):

I am also not aware of a mechanism to achieve this. But the following might give you an idea how something like a static array might be achieved.

I assing a class `static_vector` to a vector as follows:

```
x <- 1:10
class(x) <- "static_vector"
```

Next I define a new method for the assingment operator `[<-` for this class:

```
"[<-.static_vector" <- function(x, i, value) {
   if (any(i > length(x))) {
      warning("Size of vector can not be changed!")
   } else {
      class(x) <- NULL
      x[i] <- value
      class(x) <- "static_vector"
   }
   return (x)
}
```

**Edit:** Following nicola's remark, I added `any()` in the first line of the function body.

Now, the following will still work and do what is expected

```
x[5] <- 0
```

but this will issue a warning and leave x unchanged:

```
x[11] <- 11
```

There are probably other methods to define before you can be sure that there is no way to change the size of `x`.

Comment: Please, specify that this solution is not vectorized. For instance `x[c(1,11)]<-0` doesn't respect what OP is asking.

Comment: @nicola: Thanks for the  comment. As I wrote, this is not a complete solution, but simply a start point. But I'll try to adapt it for at least the simple case you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can give your array a class attribute then define a `[` method for it.  A simple version could be something like,

```
`[.thing` <- function(x, i) {
    if (i > length(x)) stop("index outside range")
    else x[[i]]
}

arr <- array(1:10, dim=c(1,10))
class(arr) <- c("thing", class(arr))

arr[1]
# [1] 1

arr[11]
# Error in `[.thing`(arr, 11) (from ...) : index outside range
```

Comment: Please, specify that this solution is not vectorized.

Comment: This won't prevent assignments, for this you have to define `[<-.thing`.

Comment: @Stibu good point.  This is far from a complete solution, just to illustrate the idea.